# SVMのコードを動かすとシンタックスエラーや index out of range エラーが出る

Tags: python, python3

Pythonによる機械学習入門を読み進んでいるところで困っています。
P119 6.2.2学習の実施で
trial_handsign_SVM.py を実行したところ以下のエラーメッセージが発生しました。
スクリプトを以下のように実行する。

```
＞＞＞run trial_handsign_SVM.py ./data/my_learn8/ ./data/my_test2/
```

`Syntax Error : invalid syntax` と表示されましたが、これはコマンドプロンプトの場合です。ちなみに、`python Spyder` でコードをそのまま実行させた時のエラーは `Index　Error:list index out of range` と表示されました。解決するためには、コードはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？また、2つのエラーの違いはあるの‌​でしょうか。厚かましいお願いではございま‌​すが、よろしくお願いします。

コードは以下の通りです。

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import os
import sys
import glob
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from sklearn import datasets

IMAGE_SIZE = 40
COLOR_BYTE = 3
CATEGORY_NUM = 6

## ラベル名(0～)を付けたディレクトリに分類されたイメージファイルを読み込む
## 入力パスはラベル名の上位のディレクトリ
def load_handimage(path):

    # ファイル一覧を取得
    files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*/*.png'))

    # イメージとラベル領域を確保
    images = np.ndarray((len(files), IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE,
                            COLOR_BYTE), dtype = np.uint8)
    labels = np.ndarray(len(files), dtype=np.int)

    # イメージとラベルを読み込み
    for idx, file in enumerate(files):
       # イメージ読み込み
       image = io.imread(file)
       images[idx] = image

       # ディレクトリ名よりラベルを取得
       label = os.path.split(os.path.dirname(file))[-1]
       labels[idx] = int(label)

    # scikit-learn の他のデータセットの形式に合わせる
    flat_data = images.reshape((-1, IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE * COLOR_BYTE))
    images = flat_data.view()
    return datasets.base.Bunch(data=flat_data,
                 target=labels.astype(np.int),
                 target_names=np.arange(CATEGORY_NUM),
                 images=images,
                 DESCR=None)
```

---

```py
from sklearn import svm, metrics

## 学習データのディレクトリ、テストデータのディレクトリを指定する
if __name__ == '__main__':
    argvs  = sys.argv
    train_path = argvs[1]
    test_path = argvs[2]

    # 学習データの読み込み
    train = load_handimage(train_path)

    # 手法:線形SVM
    classifier = svm.LinearSVC()

    # 学習
    classifier.fit(train.data, train.target)

    # テストデータの読み込み
    test = load_handimage(test_path)

    # テスト
    predicted = classifier.predict(test.data)

    # 結果表示
    print("Accuracy:\n%s" % metrics.accuracy_score(test.target, predicted))
```

Comment: すみません、エラーメッセージの内容は何ですか？

Comment: 始めたばかりでよく分からない事ばかりですが。

Comment: エラーは以下のように表示されました。

Comment: Syntax Error : invalid syntax   と表示されましたが、これはコマンドプロンプトの場合です。ちなみに、python Spyder でコードをそのまま実行させた時のエラーは　Index　Error:list index out of rangeと表示されました。解決するためには、コードはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？また、２つのエラーの違いはあるのでしょうか。厚かましいお願いではございますが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

コードのほうが間違っているのかと思い
こちらからダウンロードして自分の環境で実行してみましたが特に問題なく動作することは確認できました。
http://www.ohmsha.co.jp/data/link/978-4-274-21963-4/

```
$ python trial_handsign_SVM.py ./data/my_learn8/ ./data/my_test2/
Accuracy:
0.916666666667
```

---

> また、２つのエラーの違いはあるの‌​でしょうか。

質問者様の質問にあります2点のエラーについて

```
Index　Error:list index out of range
```

リスト内の存在しない要素にアクセスされた場合このエラーを吐きます。

```
Syntax Error : invalid syntax
```

pythonの文法エラーです。

---

> 解決するためには、コードはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

上記でも書きました通り、コードのほうに問題はありません。

コード実行時に発生したエラーをもう少し詳細に教えていただければこちらも問題の解決をお手伝いできると思います。
例えば下のような感じにエラーの内容を貼り付けてもらえると助かります。

```
$ python trial_handsign_SVM.py ./data/my_learn8/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "trial_handsign_SVM.py", line 51, in <module>
test_path = argvs[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: 申し訳ございません。パソコンを使えない状態が続いてたため、返信が返信が滞ってしました。今朝、いろいろと試してみたのですが、python-spyderno

Comment: python-spyderのコンソールでrun trial_handsign_SVM.pyと一度打ち込み、以下のようなエラーを吐き出させて、
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/kousen/WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5/examples/06/trial_handsign_SVM.py", line 50, in <module>
    train_path = argvs[1]

IndexError: list index out of range この後にもう一度　　　　　　　　run trial_handsign_SVM.py ./data/my_learn8/ ./data/my_test2/と打ち込むと　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　Accuracy:
0.916666666667　と出力させることが出来ました。理由はよく分からないのですが、一度エラーを吐き出さなければいけないようです。　　ただし、コマンドプロンプトからは出力が出来ないようです。以下のようなエラーが吐き出されます。

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 1                                                                                      run trial_handsign_SVM.py ./data/my_learn10/ ./data/other_test2/                      SyntaxError : invalid syntax

Comment: `python trial_handsign_SVM.py ./data/my_learn8/ ./data/my_test2/` か `python3 trial_handsign_SVM.py ./data/my_learn8/ ./data/my_test2/`を打つとどうなりますか

Comment: すみません。返信が遅くなりました。出力がコマンドプロンプトで出来るようになりました。うまくいかなかった方法がわかりました。恥ずかしながら、基本的なとこが間違っていたようで、コマンドの"c:￥Users￥Owner￥Desktop￥Winpython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5￥scripts＞のところで、ディレクトの指示場所にtrial_handsign_SVM.py と画像データを入れていなかったためエラーが表示されいたのだと思います。wkame 10さん、nekketsuuuさん感謝申し上げます。ありがとうございます。